# Refactor a convoluted date method

Tags: ruby, datetime

My users choose some dates from a datepicker, which is saving the dates in this format:

"06/05/2019"

I'd like the date to display back in this format: "Wednesday, June 5"

I'm struggling a bit with Ruby's date methods.  This method that I put together is working, but I'm sure if somebody could help me trim this to one line, then I would understand Ruby's date methods better.

```
def friendly_date(input)
    orig_due_date = Date.strptime(input, "%m/%d/%Y")
    orig_due_date.strftime("%A, %B %e")
end
```

Thank you in advance for any insight.

Comment: Will somebody please explain why this question is getting downvoted?

Comment: I'm going to guess because that function is not convoluted. Reducing it to one line is no improvement, though changing `orig_due_date` to simply `date` would be because it works on any date.

Comment: I'm guessing that the downvoter believed it to be a trivial question, that there is no point to define the variable and if the variable were substituted out it's obvious that no further improvement could be made.

Comment: I guess that makes sense.  But that fact wasn't obvious to me at the time.

Comment: @JeffZivkovic Hover over the downvote button and it prompts with "*This question does not show any research effort*". I imagine any downvotes are because you've shown no research you've done towards answering your own question, e.g., "I tried *x* but it didn't work because *y*." All I see is "Please make this a one-liner," not "I tried to make this a one-liner in the following ways but ..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write...

```
def friendly_date(input)
  Date.strptime(input, "%m/%d/%Y").strftime("%A, %B %e")
end
```

...but this would not be an improvement. It's doing two operations, parse and format, so it's easier to understand as two lines. Naming the variable just `date` is an improvement because inside this function its just a date.

```
def friendly_date(input)
  date = Date.strptime(input, "%m/%d/%Y")
  date.strftime("%A, %B %e")
end
```

A better way to simplify your code is to have one function parsing what the datepicker gives you into a `Date`, and other to format any `Date`.

```
def date_from_datepicker(from_datepicker)
  Date.strptime(input, "%m/%d/%Y")
end

def friendly_date(date)
  date.strftime("%A, %B %e")
end
```

Now you have a generic function to transform the datepicker format into a `Date`. And a generic function to transform any `Date` or `Time` into your preferred format.

Now you'd immediately normalize the output from your datepicker into a `Date` and only transform it into your friendly format as necessary. This will make working with all dates easier by having the be `Date` objects for as long as possible.

```
input_date = date_from_datepicker(params['date'])

...work with it like any other Date...

puts friendly_date(input_date)

# And it works on any Date.
puts friendly_date(some_other_date)
```

Answer (score 3):

I can't see any improvement except avoiding the local variable

```
def friendly_date(input)
    Date.strptime(input, "%m/%d/%Y").strftime("%A, %B %e")
end
```